# Regular expression for validating cyrillic

Tags: php

I have a php function to validate "City":

```
function validate_city($field) {
    if ($field == "") return "Enter city.<br />";
    else if (preg_match("/[^а-Яa-zA-z-]/", $field))
        return "City hame only from letters and -.<br />";
    return "";
}
```

Every time, when I enter a cyrillic City name (for ex: "Минск") it returns:
City hame only from letters and -. 
Variable $_POST['city'] looks like:
Ð�Ð¸Ð½Ñ�Ðº

In JS this code works correct, I think something is in encoding.....

Comment: I had similar problem with this one recently, for cities written in Serbian cyrillic (like `"Београд, Москва, Каиро"`). Check encoding for both pages, one where there is POST form and this one with function.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the following pattern to validate non latin characters:

```
preg_match ('/^[a-zA-Z\p{Cyrillic}\d\s\-]+$/u', $str);
```

See [this post](http://itworkarounds.blogspot.com/2011/08/validating-cyrillic-utf8-alphanumeric.html) for the full explanation

Answer (score 4):

A better solution to match Cyrillic and Common characters would be:

```
preg_match ('/^[\p{Cyrillic}\p{Common}]+$/u', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like utf-8, if it is, this tip from cebelab on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) might be helpful:

> I noticed that in order to deal with
>   UTF-8 texts, without having to
>   recompile php with the PCRE UTF-8 flag
>   enabled, you can just add the
>   following sequence at the start of
>   your pattern: (*UTF8)
>
> for instance : '#(*UTF8)[[:alnum:]]#'
>   will return TRUE for 'é' where
>   '#[[:alnum:]]#' will return FALSE

Use the builtin special character group :alnum: for this, you will need to reverse your match:

```
function validate_city($field) {
    if ($field == "") return "Enter city.<br />";
    else if (preg_match("/(*UTF8)^[[:alnum:]]+$/", $field))
    return "";
    return "City hame only from letters and -.<br />";
}
```

edit, ah, forgot utf-8 in regex ; )

Comment: elseif (preg_match("/(*UTF8)[^а-Яa-zA-z-]/", $field))
  return "City hame only from letters and -.<br /><br />";
Now even when I enter: "Минск@&%$()@" it says that everything is allright

Comment: The Characters between a and Я might include more than you intend to match, it even might span 80% of the utf-8 range. Try your regex with `[[:alnum:]]` - it contains all alphanumeric characters and is defined within php / pcre itself.

Comment: (preg_match("/(*UTF8)[[:alnum:]]/", $field)) ?

Comment: every time I see such else-if code without brackets, I want to kill the author

Comment: does it help when I say i felt bad writing this? ^^

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an encoding problem.
Put this in your page:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content='text/html;charset="UTF-8"'>
```

Or this:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content='text/html;charset="windows-1251"'>
```

Comment: I think that problem is not just in META. Consider that his PHP file must be saved as UTF-8. Transferring data between POST variable and PHP script might be a problem for Non-ANSI characters sometimes, specially if one page is saved as ANSI and another one is UTF-8 or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure all your files have the same encoding or encode/decode the data in the appropriate places. If you're working with utf-8, check:
- that your page is being displayed in the right encoding (Browser -> view -> encoding)
- that your files have the right encoding

Your database, if you have one, should also be in the same encoding you choose everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Check encoding in response headers (FireBug is a great tool). Possibly you have incorrect value in Webserver configuration (for example, `AddDefaultCharset` in .htaccess file).

PS. Use UTF regexps instead of character ranges (`preg_match("/[^\pL-]/u", $field)`)

Comment: Also, [а-Я] isnt correct range, because small russian letters are going after capitals. And dont forget about й,ё,Й and Ё - they have special code numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `$_POST['city']` looks like: `Ð�Ð¸Ð½Ñ�Ðº`

It's not an `UTF-8`.... Maybe problemis in `$_POST`?

Comment: Problem was in my function fix_string, it was ruining my cyrillic texts...

function fix_string($string) {
 if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
 return htmlentities ($string);
}

Answer (score 0):

I try to use `^[a-zA-Z\p{Cyrillic}\d\s\-]+$` in https://regex101.com/ and everything is ok.